# How to change ActionBar.Tab's strip color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

I want to change the strip color of ActionBar.Tabs and for that I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/).
But there are some errors that I cannot figure out. Here is the code in style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>


<style name="FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>


<style name="FindMyTrain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/FindMyTrain.ActionBar.Tab</item>
</style>


</resources>
```

And these are the errors:
[image: Error]

And I have no idea what am I doing wrong or what do these errors even mean. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ Asadullah Have u created color.xml?

Comment: yes i have created that

Comment: is it like, Theme.Holo.Light does not contain android:actionBarTabStyle ???

Comment: because in tutorial, they have used Theme.Sherlock instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the actionBar color, I suggest you use the `Android asset studio` [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator). It's a easy way to change the actionBar color and style. All you need to do is generate the style you want, download zip file, unzip it, copy all files (drawable folders) into your res folder and change your app theme in the AndroidManifest.xml to what you just generated from asset studio.

Comment: how does it work ??
I mean where am i supposed to add that zip file and how to use it?

Comment: unzip file and copy the all drawable folder to your res

Comment: Android asset studio is only for icon generation, isn't it ??

Comment: okay i generated a zip from there, added every thing in res folder and tab indicator color is still blue :(

Comment: Oh, you should change your app theme in the AndroidManifest.xml to what you just generated from asset studio

Comment: @bjiang Dear, Update your answer with above two steps so helpful to other users.

Comment: also, can you please tell me how can i control the height of tab strip ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Make sure your build target is set to 13.
**Project Properties -> Project Build Target = 13** or above.

```
<style name="ActionBarTab">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>


<style name="FindMyTrain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTab</item>
</style>
```

Comment: okay, 1 error is removed but one with attr 'actionBarTabStyle' still remains

Comment: I got your point.The second item containing only **actionBarTabStyle** is for Support library compatibility, i.e  to provide backward compatibility. You can remove that if you are using higher target. Check the link: [Support library compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: What is your build target?

Comment: minimum is 15 and target is 21